# stringr::str_wrap does not wrap exactly every n characters

Tags: r, regex, string

The code below doesnt insert a new line after every third character which is what i thought str_wrap. Clearly there is some other underlying logic. I also get whacky results when the string contains some special characters.

```
t<-c("The adds fundamental principle”, The discriminatory ")
str_wrap(t,3)
```

the result is

```
> str_wrap(t,3)
[1] "The\nadds\nfundamental\nprinciple"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`str_wrap` is a wrapper around `stringi::stri_wrap` which will not break individual words. Its intended use is to wrap text in paragraphs, where you wouldn't want to have a word split across lines. If you want a newline every three characters, you could extract a three character pattern `.{3}` and concatenate them together with newlines as shown. Note that spaces are left in: if you want to remove those first then you can. The second match option `{0,2}$` means that remainder characters at the end will also be returned, instead of silently being dropped.

```r
t <- c("The adds fundamental principle”, The discriminatory a")
library(stringr)
#> Warning: package 'stringr' was built under R version 3.5.1
t %>%
  str_extract_all(".{3}|.{0,2}$") %>%
  `[[`(1) %>%
  str_c(collapse="\n") %>%
  writeLines()
#> The
#>  ad
#> ds 
#> fun
#> dam
#> ent
#> al 
#> pri
#> nci
#> ple
#> ”, 
#> The
#>  di
#> scr
#> imi
#> nat
#> ory
#>  a
```

Created on 2018-07-25 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Calum You's great answer, you can also write this in a simpler way by replacing any 3-letter chunk by itself along with a newline:

```
t = c("The adds fundamental principle, The discriminatory a")
library(stringr)
out = str_replace_all(t, paste0("(.{3})"), "\\1\n")
cat(out)
#> The
#>  ad
#> ds 
#> fun
#> dam
#> ent
#> al 
#> pri
#> nci
#> ple
#> , T
#> he 
#> dis
#> cri
#> min
#> ato
#> ry 
#> a
```

Created on 2020-08-16 by the reprex package (v0.3.0)